# Create and return a new list item from within a Bindlist(of t) class?

Tags: vb.net, bindinglist

I have a situation where I'm taking advantage of events raised by a class that inherits Bindinglist(Of t).  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to create and return a new item (Of t) when the list is empty or that specific Key string is not found when using the "FIND" function shown below?  My code looks as follows:

BINDINGLIST(OF T) CLASS:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class mylist(Of t)
  Inherits BindingList(Of t)

  'find an item by keystring
  Public Function Find(ByVal KeyString) As t

    Dim myItem As t

    'Check if any objects of t exist in the list
    If Me.Items.Count > 0 Then

        Dim properties As PropertyDescriptorCollection = _
                    TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me.Items(0).GetType)

        'find the key property
        Dim myProperty As PropertyDescriptor = properties.Find("Key", False)

        'search for string match
        For Each myItem In Me.Items
            If myProperty.GetValue(myItem) = KeyString Then
                Return myItem
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next

        'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP:
        'need to assign default property values to myitem of t and return

    End If
        'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP:
        'need to assign default property values to myitem of t and return
  End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a constraint on your generic type parameter to require that it has a parameterless constructor.

```
Public Class MyList(Of T As New)
```

You can then create an instance of that type by invoking that constructor as you would for any other type, e.g.

```
Return New T
```

Note that your class will then only be able to store items of a type that has a parameterless constructor.  If that's a limitation that you can't accept then you will simply not be able to create an instance of `T` because there is no single way to create an instance of an arbitrary type.